# Substituting 0A For \n

Tags: c++, file-io, hex

I'm at the time beginning the development of a simple hex editor(that only reads at the time). I want to substitute `OA` for `"\n"`, I'm trying with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   ifstream infile;
   int crtchar = (int)infile.get();
   infile.open("test.txt", ifstream::in);
   while(infile.good())
   {
      if(crtchar != 0xA)
         cout << hex << setfill('0') << setw(2) << crtchar << ":";
      else
         cout << endl;
   }
   cout << "\n=====================================\n";
   infile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

It compiles without errors, but when I try to execute it, I just got nothing:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Nathan Campos\Desktop>hex
>
> =====================================
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\Nathan Campos\Desktop>

This is happening just after I've added the feature to substitute `OA` for `\n`, because before it was working very nice. **What is wrong?**

Comment: Are you sure you were running exactly the same program except for the switch of `0xA` for `'\n'`? Is EOL-translation biting you? If you truly do get different behaviour for the two, have you tried printing the integer value of `'\n'`? Why do you even want to avoid the more readable (and more portable) `'\n'` in favour of `0xA`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You realize that you are only reading a character **once**, and *before even opening the file*, at that?

Answer (score 3):

Sigh. You try to read the file before you open it.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you first `open(...)` your file and then try to `get()` from it?
Also, shouldn't you do more `get()`'s inside your while loop

Answer (score 0):

Put `int crtchar = (int)infile.get();` inside a `while(infile.good())` and give it a try.